# jQuery - Enlarge clicked div and back to original size if clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
     content
</div>
<div class="box last">
     content
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.box').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: "+=100",
        height: "+=100",
        top: "-=50",
        left: "-=50"
    }, 300);
    $(this).addClass('zoom')
});
```

I need to resize box back to original state (size and position), if click is happened on another box or somewhere outside (document body).

I have tried with this code, but code is executed as soon as i click on one of the boxes:

```
$(document).on('click', ".box.zoom", function () {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: "-=100",
        height: "-=100",
        top: "+=50",
        left: "+=50"
    }, 300);
    $(this).removeClass('zoom')
});
```

**Current setup is located on:** https://jsfiddle.net/3ftg4hmc/

Comment: please confirm, if a box is clicked continuously, the size should get increases, and when the other box is clicked, the first box size should get resized and positioned to default one?

Answer (score 0):

At the very last of click event save current position using `data()` method of the box and on the next click restore previous position like following.

```
$('.box').on('click', function () {
    var position = $(this).data('position'); //get saved position

    if ($(this).hasClass('zoom')) {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "-=100",
            height: "-=100",
            top: position.top, //use saved position
            left: position.left //use saved position
        }, 300);
        $(this).removeClass('zoom');
    } else {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "+=100",
            height: "+=100",
            top: "-=50",
            left: "-=50"
        }, 300);
        $(this).addClass('zoom')
    }

    $(this).data('position', $(this).offset());
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3ftg4hmc/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but only one box at a time should be opened. For example if box1 is opened, clicking on box2 should close box1.

Comment: Use `$('.zoom').not(this).removeAttr('style').removeClass('zoom');`. See https://jsfiddle.net/3ftg4hmc/4/ @RhymeGuy

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope this helps you

Javascript

```
$('.box').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if ($(this).hasClass('zoom')) {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "-=100",
            height: "-=100",
            top: "+=50",
            left: "+=50"
        }, 300);
        $(this).removeClass('zoom');
    }
    else {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "+=100",
            height: "+=100",
            top: "-=50",
            left: "-=50"
        }, 300);
        $(this).addClass('zoom');
    }
});
```

link https://jsfiddle.net/3ftg4hmc/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
    width: "+=100",
    height: "+=100",
    top: "-=50",
    left: "-=50"
  }, 300);
  $(this).siblings().attr("style", ""); // new line added
});
```

you could just empty the attribute `style` of sibling div's by just using `$(this).siblings().attr("style", "");`

here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3ftg4hmc/3/